# Realizar query según posición del valor en una tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla con diferentes resultados donde en cada uno quiero abrir una nueva ventana realizando una nueva query pasando como parámetros el nombre de la columna y el valor de la fila actual.
Se puede controlar la posición de una tabla y en tal caso realizar dicha consulta?

Tengo la siguiente tabla, donde me gustaria coger "**bill1**" de la columna "**BCN**"

```
+--------+----------+----------+
|  Name  |   BCN    |    MAD   |
+--------+----------+----------+
| user1  |  bill1   |  bill1   |
| user2  |  bill2   |  bill2   |
| user3  |  bill3   |  bill3   |
| user4  |  bill4   |  bill4   |
| user5  |  bill5   |  bill5   |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

En este caso, al seleccionar "bill2" en la columna BCN, tendria que coger el valor de "user2" en Name por lo que se lanzaria una query semejante a:

`Select * from table where BCN = 'bill2' and Name 'user2'`

Hay forma de realizar algo así?

La tabla la genero de la siguiente manera:

```
 while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $id = $test['id']; 
 echo"<td>".$test['name']."</td>";
 echo"<td><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#add_new_record_modal' class=text-dark>".$test['BCN']."</a></td>";
 echo"<td><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#add_new_record_modal' class=text-dark>".$test['MAD']."</a></td>";
 echo"<td><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#add_new_record_modal' class=text-dark>".$test['planned']."</a></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
 mysql_close($conn);
 ?>
</table>
```

y la ventana (modal) la abro de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add_new_record_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

<?php
include("conn.php");

//$result = mysql_query("Select * from table where BCN = '$columna1' and Name '$fila2'
$result = mysql_query("Select * from table where BCN = 'bill2' and Name 'user2'");

while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $test['id']; 
    echo"<div class='form-group'>";
    echo"<label for='s'>".$columna1." ".$columna2."</label>";
    echo"</div>";
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Si.. pero necesitariamos ver tu codigo para ajustarlo a lo que necesitas.

Comment: @gbianchi actualizo post

Comment: alguien puede orientarme?

Comment: No se entiende tu problema.donde esta la dificultad? Porque parece que estas contando como hacer algo, pero no se ve una dificultad por ningun lado.

Comment: Actualmente todos los links son iguales. Lo que necesitaria es poder controlar en que celda exatamente estoy para coger como variables el "name" de la fila y el nombre de la columna

Comment: Ahh tu pregunta es como pasar valores a un form modal.

Comment: eso es. al Hacer click en una celda, me abre un modal y se deberá de realizar una query según en que celda esté.

Comment: Tu pregunta es: como pasarle parametros a un formulario modal. No esta en ninguna parte de tu pregunta eso. Fijate si no esta respondido en el sitio ya. Suerte!

Comment: donde puedo encontrarlo?